# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't start - MSVCR100.dll related problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll

When I want to start VS10 Ultimate, I get this error:

**Title: denenv.exe - Entry Point Not Found**

**Message : The procedure entry point wmemcpy_s could not be located in the dynamic link library MSVCR100.dll.**

There are a couple of files with this name in my Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 folder.
Which one should I replace, and more important with what version of the file.
Will that solve my problem?

P.S:
OS : Windows 7 x64

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling (or a "repair install")? If this is screwed up, who knows what else might be?

Comment: @Michael Burr no. it's the last resort.

Comment: why a last resort?  It should be a pretty easy operation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I replaced MSVCR100.dll from %WinDir%/System32 and %WinDir%/SysWOW64 with a version of the file from a friend's computer who had Vs10 installed and properly working.

Comment: See H3llGhost's answer for the better way to solve the problem - not generally a good idea to copy DLLs from other location - plus it may fix other problems that you aren't aware of.

Comment: Trust me, that was the first thing I did and it didn't work (for me).

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the Visual C++ Runtime, which you can find in the MS Download Center.

- [Visual C++ Runtime 2010 (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=bd512d9e-43c8-4655-81bf-9350143d5867)
- [Visual C++ Runtime 2010 (x68)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with vs2012.
I didn't want to borrow a copy from a friend, I have no friends ;).
I tried reinstalling VC++ runtimes for 2010 and 2012, didnt work.
I went to control panel -> programs and features.
right click on Microsoft Visual Studio.
chose repair, that worked for me.